# VS project unload and reload

Tags: visual-studio

My solution is way too big, and when I work on a specific feature, I am unloading un-needed projects to speed up the compilation process.
However, when I need to reload everything back in the solution, it literally takes ages. I once waited around 2 hours for it. I think that was for about 40 projects. Why does it take that long? Is there a simple workaround of closing the solution, editing something in the .sou file, and then opening it again with all projects loaded? It just drives me nuts at the moment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of loading/unloading the projects - "`Right-Click on the Solution`" -> "`Configuration Manager...`" -> Uncheck the checbox opposite the project which you don't want to build.